# what module can generate themes for every module

Tags: drupal, module, themes

in some case in drupal theme page I got themes for every module, what module or mmistake can did  this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove non-theme folders from sites/all/themes, /themes and sites/x/themes where x is the site name if you are running multisite structure.

That happens because themes and modules both have the same .info file structure.